# How can I insert records into MySql table so that one cell has multiple values?

Tags: mysql, insert

Sorry if the title is confusing, here's what I want to do:

```
INSERT INTO table (fruit, type) VALUES 
('apple', '1'), 
('apple', '2'), 
('apple', '2'), 
('banana', '3'), 
('banana', '4'), 
('banana', '5');
```

So that the resulting table only has two rows with pipe-separated values in the `type` column that look like this:

```
('apple', '1|2') 
('banana', '3|4|5')
```

Right now I have:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table ( 
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  fruit varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY, 
  type varchar(100) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;  

INSERT INTO table (fruit, type) VALUES 
('apple', '1'), 
('apple', '2'), 
('apple', '2'), 
('banana', '3'), 
('banana', '4'), 
('banana', '5') 
ON KEY DUPLICATE type = VALUES(type)|type 
//I know above line is wrong and this is where I'm stuck
```

Is it possible for me to get a series of pipe-separated values in the `type` column?

Many thanks

**EDIT:**

I got almost where I want to end up by doing this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table ( 
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  fruit varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY, 
  type varchar(100) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;  

INSERT INTO table (fruit, type) VALUES 
('apple', '1'), 
('apple', '2'), 
('apple', '2'), 
('banana', '3'), 
('banana', '4'), 
('banana', '5') 
ON KEY DUPLICATE UPDATE type = CONCAT(type, '|', VALUES(type))
```

The only issue is that the resulting rows are:

```
('apple', '1|2|2')
('banana', '3|4|5')
```

I'm trying out different methods of DISTINCT to get rid of that last '2' but I keep getting MySql errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL's command is called `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

And if you want to keep it in the order you show (like `('banana', '3|4|5')`) you should use it like this:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE type = CONCAT(type, '|', VALUES(type))
```

since `VALUES` refers to the new value that is trying to be inserted on the existing record.

If you want to avoid repeated values, try with:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE type = IF(type LIKE CONCAT('%', VALUES(type), '%'), type, CONCAT(type, '|', VALUES(type)) )
```

I agree that this is not the best way to handle a DB, but if this is what you want, this should do the trick.

From: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: This didn't work when I first tried but when I changed it to ON DUPLICATE KEY *UPDATE* it worked. Now just need to get rid of duplicate values that are being pipe-separated in the cell

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I used what you wrote and tried to correct it, but in the first sentence it was ok. What are the results you are getting with this?

Comment: Ahh I see. I'm getting ('apple', '1|2|2') ('banana', '3|4|5') so I'd like to just get ('apple', '1|2') for this row. That way If I try to add many more 'apple','2' then the row will ignore duplicate values and remain the same

Comment: I edited the answer with a solution for duplicates. Please let me know if this works.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I could help you :). Still don't know why someone downvoted on this answer, since it was in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Insert of inserting data with pipe separation, you can insert data into the database normally like so:

```
create table test(id int, fruit varchar(50), type varchar(100));
INSERT INTO test (fruit, type) VALUES 
('apple', '1'), 
('apple', '2'), 
('apple', '2'), 
('banana', '3'), 
('banana', '4'), 
('banana', '5');
```

Then write a query like this to extract data in the manner you want:

```
select fruit, group_concat(distinct type separator '|') as type
from test
group by fruit

Result:
fruit   type
apple   1|2
banana  3|4|5
```

SQLFiddle Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90a9b/1

You can even create a view like this:

```
create view test_pipedelimited as 
select fruit, group_concat(distinct type separator '|') as type
from test
group by fruit;
```

And then always just use to get results in pipe-delimited format

```
select * from test_pipedelimited
```

**Procedure**

If you really, really want to store type with pipe-delimitation, you could do that through a stored procedure like this:

```
delimiter //
create procedure insert_data_into_test (
    p_fruit varchar(50),  -- takes fruit as first argument
    p_type varchar(100),  -- takes type as second argument
    OUT p_id int -- populates this variable with -1 if it was an update or with last inserted ID if it was an insert
)
begin

   -- find out if the fruit is already in the table
    declare fruit_count int;
    select count(*) into fruit_count from test where fruit = p_fruit;

    -- if fruit is in the table, do an update
    if fruit_count > 0 then
        update test set type = concat(type, '|', p_type) where fruit = p_fruit;
        set p_id = -1;

    -- if fruit is NOT in the table, do an insert
    else
        insert into test (fruit, type) values (p_fruit, p_type);
        select last_insert_id() into p_id;

    end if; 

end; //
delimiter ;
```

**How do you call this procedure?**

```
create table test (id int primary key auto_increment, fruit varchar(50), type varchar(100));

-- create the procedure here, technically

call insert_data_into_test('apple', '1', @id);
select @id;
Result: 1

select * from test;
ID fruit  type
1  apple  1

call insert_data_into_test('apple', '2', @id);
select @id;
Result: -1

select * from test;
ID fruit  type
1  apple  1|2

call insert_data_into_test('toast', '3', @id);
select @id;
Result: 2

select * from test;
ID fruit  type
1  apple  1|2
2  toast  3
```

**Recommendation**

I highly recommend not storing data like that in a database. True power of the database will be realized by storing data methodically and following some known normalization rules. This technique violates the first rule of normalization (1NF).

It will also limit you when you want to avoid inserting duplicate types. Let's say you enter `apple` and `1` and you do that again. You will get type of `1|1`. To prevent that, you would have to go do much more work to find out if 1 is present in type. You cannot just do `LIKE type = '%1%'` because that would match 1, 11, 21 etc. You can't sanely find out max type for each fruit etc.

**Better procedure**

```
delimiter //
create procedure insert_data_into_test (
    p_fruit varchar(50),  -- takes fruit as first argument
    p_type varchar(100),  -- takes type as second argument
    OUT p_id int -- populates this variable with -1 if it was an update or with last inserted ID if it was an insert
)
begin

   -- find out if the fruit is already in the table
    declare fruit_count int;
    declare fruit_type_count int;
    select count(*) into fruit_count from test where fruit = p_fruit;

    -- if fruit is in the table, do an update
    if fruit_count > 0 then

        -- let's check if the the type is already there for the fruit       
        -- we don't want to put duplicates in
        select count(*) into fruit_type_count 
        from test 
        where 
            fruit = p_fruit 
            and (                                                               -- if p_type was 2
                    type regexp concat('^', p_type, '$')            -- ^2$ regex matches if type starts and ends with 2
                    or type regexp concat('^', p_type, '\\|')   -- ^2| regex matches if type starts with 2| (the \\ is to prevent MySQL from giving a special meaning to |)
                    or type regexp concat('\\|', p_type, '\\|')     -- |2| regex matches if type is in the middle somewhere
                    or type regexp concat('\\|', p_type, '$')       -- |2$ regex matches if type is at the end but there's something before it
                );

        -- only update type if the type is not already present      
        if fruit_type_count = 0 then    
            update test set type = concat(type, '|', p_type);
        end if;
        set p_id = -1;

    -- if fruit is NOT in the table, do an insert
    else
        insert into test (fruit, type) values (p_fruit, p_type);
        select last_insert_id() into p_id;

    end if; 

end; //
delimiter ;
```

This better procedure accounts for duplicates and doesn't insert a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @zedfoxus but I need to be able to stored them in the database as pipe-separated values. So that when a new entry of ('apple', '9') is entered, the resulting row in the database itself is ('apple', '1|2|9').

Comment: You'll might be able to do that with triggers. Are you familiar with triggers? I highly recommend to **not** store data in databases like how you want. That's called denormalized design and will most likely turn out difficult to handle in the long run. Are you still wanting to store data like that? If so, I can whip up a trigger for an example.

Comment: I am not familiar but I'll look into them now. But yes, that would be great if you could! The data handling will not be an issue as the table is just being used to reference when needed and we'd like it to look as clean as possible without having to run a SELECT after every update

Comment: Any luck @zedfoxus ? I've been working with triggers but am struggling to succeed

Comment: I'm sure I'll come up with something. Right now I am a bit busy but will definitely take a crack at it in a few hours, or later at night

Comment: Thanks! So far my trigger looks like this:


"delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER ins_list BEFORE AND AFTER UPDATE ON table
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
  UPDATE table SET type = group_concat(distinct type separator '|') WHERE type = NEW.type;
 END;
| delimiter ;"   then I insert my values but the outcome is ('apple', '2'), ('banana', '5')

Comment: Triggers won't cut it, I realized. I have created a stored procedure in the answer that will help you through the process.

Comment: I've made changes to my query, edited in OP. Almost there!

Comment: Are you expecting me to provide you a full solution?

Comment: No... I'm updating you on my progress since I took a different route than the triggers or procedure.

Comment: I think you did quite well in your attempt. The deal with `on duplicate` is that it will check the contents of the entire key and so you will not be able to achieve exactly what you want. Let me update my procedure a little bit since I see you are trying your hardest to resolve this as well.

Comment: I've changed the procedure a bit so that it prevents duplicates from being entered

Comment: Hi @zedfoxus thanks for all the help and time you took putting together the procedure. In the end, if you look down at JuanBoca's edited answer that was able to do the trick. While I have faith in the procedure method, my skills are not yet there to fully understand how to work with it effectively. Best, Randy

Comment: That's absolutely fine. No worries.